# Ajax and MySQL on Wordpress

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to branch out into Ajax calls for some of my MySQL queries on a Wordpress site I run. To do this I've been following the example [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp).

I haven't modified the javascript component, only the `form` and then I'm using a very simple snippet of php to see if $q is getting fed to php or not.

On page startup I'm getting the correct echo `ALL` however on selecting anything in the dropdown menu I'm finding that there is no change in the echo of $q.

What am I missing here? I'm using Google Chrome as my browser if that is an issue.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a team:</option>
  <option value="HAW">Hawks</option>
  <option value="GEE">Cats</option>
  <option value="ADE">Crows</option>
  <option value="WCE">Eagles</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Team info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

My simple php code is:

```
$q = $_GET['q'] ?: 'ALL';
echo $q;
```

Comment: You'll need to use `isset($_GET['q'])` to check whether there is `q` in the url params. So your first line would be `$q = isset($_GET['q'])?$_GET['q']:ALL;` If you directly open `getuser.php on your browser, you'll encounter this error in PHP 7.1

Comment: And what's the `ALL` variable? is it a global variable? a definition? A list which you get from your database (if it is, where's the dollar sign?). I'm getting __Notice: Use of undefined constant ALL__ error

Comment: Sorry, ALL isn’t a variable, I’ve fixed that in the code snippet above. Its VARCHAR I look up in my MySQL query

Comment: check for `isset($_GET['q'])`. Before moving to the ajax, console the value that you are passing (named `str`). Check whether you are getting the value or not

Comment: Maybe your PHP is silently throwing errors? You can easily test whether the server script, `getuser.php`, is working properly by opening that file directly on a new Chrome tab. For me, if I'm passing `q` in url params, (such as `getuser.php?q=VAL`), the script is echoing its value (in this case, VAL). If there's no `q`, the script is echoing `ALL`. If this is not working, either the bug is in some other code or you're missing the `isset` check.

Comment: Wow, still supporting IE5 are we?
But seriously: Check the developer tools:
- Is the request fired?
- Do you get a 200 status from the server? 
- If so: what's the response
- If 400/500 status: check the server logs

Comment: `$q = isset($_GET['q'])?$_GET['q']: 'ALL';` doesn't seem to help the process. I opened Chrome Developer Console and `getuser.php?q=VAL` was being called but was saying `404 Page Not Found`. I'm just trying to find a really simple example of a dropdown menu that can feed a php variable via ajax. I've tried a lot of the examples on the net with no success. Once I get a simple example working I can build from there what I need.